# Не получается поместить элементы в массив php

Tags: php, массивы, json

Есть массив $items, его содержимое:

```js
[
  {"product_id":105756483,"offer_id":"A2274","stock":{
    "coming":0,"present":0,"reserved":0
  }},
  {"product_id":105757609,"offer_id":"A2275","stock":{
    "coming":0,"present":0,"reserved":0
  }},
  {"product_id":105759812,"offer_id":"A1143","stock":{
    "coming":0,"present":0,"reserved":0
  }},
  {"product_id":105761607,"offer_id":"A2585","stock":{
    "coming":0,"present":0,"reserved":0
  }},
  {"product_id":105763167,"offer_id":"A2588","stock":{
    "coming":0,"present":0,"reserved":0
  }}
]
```

Перебираю его с помощью foreach:

```php
$stocks = [];
foreach ($items as $k => $v) {
  $stocks = [
     'offer_id'  =>  $v['offer_id'], 
     'product_id' => $v['product_id'],
     'stock' => $v['stock']['present'],
     'warehouse_id' => '22222222222222',
  ];

  $array = json_encode($stocks);
  print_r($array);  
}
```

В результате получаю json такого вида:

```js
{"offer_id":"A2274","product_id":105756483,"stock":0,"warehouse_id":"22222222222222"}
{"offer_id":"A2275","product_id":105757609,"stock":0,"warehouse_id":"22222222222222"}
{"offer_id":"A1143","product_id":105759812,"stock":0,"warehouse_id":"22222222222222"}
{"offer_id":"A2585","product_id":105761607,"stock":0,"warehouse_id":"22222222222222"}
{"offer_id":"A2588","product_id":105763167,"stock":0,"warehouse_id":"22222222222222"}
```

А нужно получить json вот в таком виде:

```js
{
  "stocks":[
    {"offer_id":"A2274","product_id":105756483,"stock":0,"warehouse_id":"22222222222222"},
    {"offer_id":"A2275","product_id":105757609,"stock":0,"warehouse_id":"22222222222222"},
    {"offer_id":"A1143","product_id":105759812,"stock":0,"warehouse_id":"22222222222222"},
    {"offer_id":"A2585","product_id":105761607,"stock":0,"warehouse_id":"22222222222222"},
    {"offer_id":"A2588","product_id":105763167,"stock":0,"warehouse_id":"22222222222222"}
  ]
}
```

Не получается. Что делаю не так?

Comment: Выводите просто по 1 строке... Собирайте сперва всё в массив, а после foreach уже делайте json_encode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
$stocks = [
  'stocks' => []  // В массиве $stocks создаем один элемент
];
foreach ($items as $k => $v) {
  $stocks['stocks'][] = [  // добавляем в него новые значения
     'offer_id'  =>  $v['offer_id'], 
     'product_id' => $v['product_id'],
     'stock' => $v['stock']['present'],
     'warehouse_id' => '22222222222222',
  ];
}
$array = json_encode($stocks);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Да! Это работает. Спасибо большое!